# 2D filter using footprint on specified pixels

Tags: image-processing, signals, vectorization

I would like to characterize the background signal around specified pixels using a handmade function. As it will be applied to a large amount of data, I try to find an efficient (vectorized) solution. Easy with e.g. scipy.ndimage.generic_filter with a given kernel but I currently fail to apply it only to **specific** pixels of my matrix and not the whole. It would only require an additional mask-like argument to point to those pixels but it doesn't exist for this function. Maybe someone knows a workaround or another way to approach the problem?

Thank you in advance!

A generic example where I do not find how to use specific_pixels:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import generate_binary_structure


def test_func(values):
    print values
    return values.sum()

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])

specified_pixels=np.zeros((3,4))
specified_pixels[1,1]=1; specified_pixels[2,2]=1

footprint=generate_binary_structure(2,2)
footprint[1,1]=False

results = ndimage.generic_filter(x, test_func, footprint=footprint)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"characterize the background signal around specified pixels"* can you please give an example of the desired behaviour or output, the question seems to be unclear to me, also you want to *"apply it only to specific pixels"* can you describe how did you choose this pixels? or how they will be selected? depending on value, positoin, etc ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm working on a wildfire detection from satellite images. Both the background characterization and the specified pixels are arbitrary. But in my case, I will compute some averages and deviations in the kernel around a pixel. Each of these pixels are possible wildfires detected in a previous step.

Comment: if you can add a sample image (before the wildfire, after the wildfire) to your question, so the problem will be more clear in order to solve it.

Comment: Well, my question is not about the detection but only the implementation, i.e. I'm not asking how to detect a wildfire but how to implement a vectorized kernel filter for specified pixels. I provided a test_func, it could be any other function for any other problem! Let's say I want to blur a picture with a 3x3 pixel kernel but only specified pixels, my question would stay the same.Thank you for your help!